# How do I map over a tibble with R lang?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a tibble. Each row in my tibble contains a url and a name. I'd like to map over each row in this tibble, and pass the complete row to a function (scrape_function).

```
pagelist
# A tibble: 10 × 2
   href                         text            
   <chr>                        <chr>           
 1 /page-one.html               page name       
 2 /page-two.html               page 2 name
 3 /page-three.html             page 3 name       
 4 /page-four.html              page 4 name  
 5 /page-five.html              page 5 name   
... etc ...
```

How do I do this? I thought something like `map_dfr` might work, but in the code below, I'm getting an error `Error:` x `must be a string of length 1`. How do I pass the entire row to the function?

```
pagelist %>%
  map_dfr(function(x) { scrape_function(x) } )
```

Comment: What is the input for `scrape_function`

Comment: `map(pagelist$href, scrape_function)`

Comment: @akrun, at the moment, it just takes the tibble row.

Comment: @onyambu that only passes the href, what if I need other elements within the row?

Comment: I meant the arguments for `scrape_function`, when you say a row, I would assume it takes two arguments i.e. for href and text

Comment: @akrun, it takes the whole row.

Comment: @purpletonic your code is not reproducible as the function was not showed.  But for more than two arguments or so, you can use `pmap`

Comment: Then use `map2` as shown in the answer. `map2(pagelist$href, pagelist$text, scrape_function)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We may use `map2` if the function takes two arguments i.e. the 'href' and 'text'

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
pagelist %>%
     mutate(out = map2(href, text, ~ scrape_function(.x, .y))) %>%
     unnest(out)
```

If there are more than two arguments to be taken, then use `pmap`

```
pagelist %>%
    mutate(out = pmap(across(everything()), ~ scrape_function(..1, ..2, ..3)))
```

Comment: Thanks, akrun. I feel like this is close. The function returns a tibble_row (which I can change) this will result in a column called `out` that contains a nested tibble. What's the better way to append these columns or create the new tibble?

Comment: @purpletonic At the end you can add `%>% tidyr::unnest(out)`.  I didn't use `pmap_dfr` or `map2_dfr` as the output derived is not clear.

Comment: What would map2_dfr do in this instance? I was struggling to understand from the docs

Comment: @purpletonic `_dfr` returns a data.frame after rowbinding the list elements, `_dfc` - returns a data.frame/tibble after column binding the list elements.  As the elements are inside `mutate`, it is better to return a `list` and later unnest